# very low resolution in ubuntu 16.04, missing driver? [dual boot windows7, HP]

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, intel-graphics

I installed Ubuntu16.04 (UEFI) on pre-installed Win10 on my HP-Zbook. The booting would not work, so I added `nomodeset` to my grub. After I also added `nouveau.modeset=0` to my grub setup during the boot. Now, I can successfully login to my ubuntu, but the resolution is too low. The icons and everything is too big. 
I was not able to change the resolution from the display setting (locked at 1024X768(4:3)).

My graphics card details :

```
inxi -G
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Skylake Integrated Graphics
           Card-2: NVIDIA GM107GLM [Quadro M2000M]
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: fbdev (unloaded: vesa) FAILED: nouveau
           Resolution: 1024x768@76.00hz
           GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.8, 256 bits)
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 12.0.6
```

My kernal is `4.8.0-41`. I tried installing `nvidia-367` and other versions, but I was then stuck in the login loop. I also got `missing firmware for module` warning and installed `kbl-dmc` driver from the Intel's dump.

Could someone please tell me, what am I missing?

My `secure boot` is disabled and `legacy mode` is enabled.

I have followed all the steps as mentioned in this post
[Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics)

Comment: Nvidia recommends 375 only for your card.

Comment: Thanks @CelticWarrior, I couldn't solve this issue. So, i installed 16.10 with nvidia-375 and I was able to get it work. Still I am unable to use my external monitor, I will post it as an additional question.